# CakePHP: Error when renaming class model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I have a class model ( in CakePHP 2.1.3) like below:

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class MemberRegister extends AppModel
{
    public function getUserByID($userID)
    {
       try {
           return $this->find('all', array(
              'fields' => array('MemberRegister.id', 'MemberRegister.first_name', 'MemberRegister.last_name'),
              'conditions' => array('MemberRegister.id' => $userID),
           ));
      } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $this->log($ex->getMessage(), LOG_ERROR);
      }
      return array();
    }

   public $useTable = 'tbl_member';
}
```

This class is run well.

But now i want to **rename class to UserRegister**. It became to:

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class UserRegister extends AppModel
{
    public function getUserByID($userID)
    {
       try {
           return $this->find('all', array(
              'fields' => array('MemberRegister.id', 'MemberRegister.first_name', 'MemberRegister.last_name'),
              'conditions' => array('MemberRegister.id' => $userID),
           ));
      } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $this->log($ex->getMessage(), LOG_ERROR);
      }
      return array();
    }

   public $useTable = 'tbl_member';
}
```

When i call method getUserByID, it have error log:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'MemberRegister.id' in 'field list'
```

and sql log:

```
 SELECT MemberRegister.id,MemberRegister.first_name,       MemberRegister.last_name FROM `tbl_member` AS `UserRegister`  WHERE MemberRegister.id = 27
```

This SQL shown that i called "AS UserRegister" is the reason of error.
( Exactly must be "AS MemberRegister" ).

To solve above problem I can have 2 options:

1. Change code in find method to:

   ```
   return $this->find('all', array(
           'fields' => array('UserRegister.id', 'UserRegister.first_name', 'UserRegister.last_name'),
           'conditions' => array('UserRegister.id' => $userID),
       ));
   ```

It will be ok.

2. Change to : "AS MemberRegister".

In fact, i dont want to use first option, because i have to change much thing in some Controllers ( where call method getUserByID) , I only want to use second option.

But I dont know how to set "AS MemberRegister" in my code, because it seams that code auto fixed with my class name: my class name is UserRegister then SQL always is "AS UserRegister",
can not change to "MemberRegister", right?

I tried to add code: 'alias' => 'MemberRegister',

but it it not run.

Please help me to solve it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `$name` property as such:

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class UserRegister extends AppModel
{
    public $name = 'MemberRegister';
    public $useTable = 'tbl_member';

    public function getUserByID($userID)
    {
       try {
           return $this->find('all', array(
              'fields' => array('MemberRegister.id', 'MemberRegister.first_name', 'MemberRegister.last_name'),
              'conditions' => array('MemberRegister.id' => $userID),
           ));
      } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $this->log($ex->getMessage(), LOG_ERROR);
      }
      return array();
    }
}
```